# @@ROWCOUNT in OSQL returns different result than in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, osql

I am experiencing some strange behavior with OSQL, and would appreciate any help.

I have a batch file that will copy a database field from one column to another.  Here is a sample script:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.EmailAddress = Table2.GenericField FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID WHERE GenericField LIKE '%@%.%' 
   AND EmailAddress IS NULL;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Assuming all the EmailAddress fields are NOT NULL anymore, I would expect the update statement to return a @@ROWCOUNT of 0.

- Example 1:

Running the above query in Query Analyzer gives me 0 for the @@ROWCOUNT.  That's good.

- Example 2:

Test.Sql contains the exact same SQL statement as above.  If I use the following OSQL statement, I also get a 0 for the @@ROWCOUNT:

```
osql.exe -D TestConn -U UserID -P pwd -s , -h-1 -w 100 -n ^
    -i "C:\Scripts\Test.sql"
```

- Example 3:

If I have the SQL statement in the batch file instead of a SQL file, I get a @@ROWCOUNT of **2**:

```
osql.exe -D TestConn -U UserID -P pwd -s , -h-1 -w 100 -n -Q ^
  "SET NOCOUNT ON; 
   UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.EmailAddress = Table2.GenericField FROM Table1
   INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID WHERE GenericField LIKE '%@%.%' 
      AND EmailAddress IS NULL;
   SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;"
```

Do I have a switch set wrong for example 3?  Why would I suddenly get a @@ROWCOUNT of 2 instead of 0?

The first time I ran the script, I got a @@ROWCOUNT of 5, when only three records were updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batch files expand `%` to a variable.  You can escape it by using double `%%`s:

```
WHERE GenericField LIKE '%%@%%.%%'
```

Comment: Brilliant, that's it!  I clearly didn't even think of that.  Thanks again!